# Get user from the middleware in Aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

How to expose information from an authorization middleware, such as the logged-in user to the subsequent request controllers with Aqueduct?

Eg my route is:

```
.route('/events/[:id]')
.link(() => SecretKeyAuthorizer(context))
.link(() => EventsController(context));
```

And the SecretKeyAuthorizer uses a header to find the current User. And I'd like to use the information from the User in the EventsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I finally found the answer. One can use attachments that is a dictionary for that purpose in the request object, kept for its lifetime. So typically the Authorizer would do something like:

```
  request.attachments["user"] = user;
```

And the subsequent RessourceControllers can use it with :

```
  User user = request.attachments["user"] as User;
```

Note that *request*, is a member of the "Controller" class, so it is directly accessible through inheritance.